# After selection of multiple values from dropdown menu inside checkbox page redirect with all values in query string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on some tasks, but I am stuck. I have below code for Drop down menu with inside Checkbox, I want to redirect the HTML page with selected multiple values on another HTML page. Thanks and appreciation for helping.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <title></title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
                rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <link href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css"
                rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"
                type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function() {$('#chkveg').multiselect({includeSelectAllOption: true});});

        function myFunction() {

        window.location.assign('test.php?rt='+$('#chkveg').val());

        }
         </script>

            <form id="form1">
        <select id="chkveg" multiple="multiple" onchange="myFunction();">

        <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>

        <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>

        <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>

        <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>

        <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>

        <option value="onions">Onions</option>

        </select>
        </form>
```

Comment: what's the problem? errors?

Comment: `.val()` in this case returns an array so you have to serialise it http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/

Comment: but it may become very complicated, because i want to load this dropdown with database by using php. if any other solution, I actually want to send selected values in URL as query string

Comment: Selecting _one_ option will already trigger the change event - so if you redirect to another page then, the user will never be able to select more than one, which means making it a multiple select is rather pointless to begin with. // Why don’t you just use a normal form, and submit that? Set a proper action and method, give your select field a name attribute - done. No JS required. (Apart from the submit issue; would make sense to use a button for that, instead of having it submit automatically, if you really want the user to be able to select more than one option.)

Comment: Thanks CBore for your reply. Actually, I want to fetch record from database by using dropdown multi item selection. eg.US, Uk, Irland or more related record fetch from database